# How can I access the property of an object in PHP from the result of a separate PHP file?

Tags: php, api, object, post, get

I'll try to keep this short and to the point. I'm setting up an API which requires using POST to generate an 'authorization token', which I can then use in combination with GET to retrieve data. The results are in JSON format, of course. I have an auth.php file which works and gives the token, among other object properties. My question is how do I use the token in a separate GET.php file to retrieve the data I need?

Is there a way to access Object properties from the end result of my auth.php file?

Here is the code which isn't working in my GET.php file:

````
if (isset($_POST['TOKEN'])) {
    $api_key = '11111111111111111111111111111';
    $utoken = $_POST['TOKEN'];
    $url = 'https://api.rmaster.com/api/daltonwholesale/catalogattributes?company='.$company.'&catseq='.$catseq.'&api_key='.$api_key;
    $company = '99';
    $catseq = '98838';

    $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$result) {die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
} else {
    echo $_POST['TOKEN'];
}

?>```
````

Comment: This is pretty impossible for us to answer since we have no idea about the application flow, how or where this file is loaded, where you create the object or even what object you're referring to. Are the properties public? Using getters?

Comment: I apologize for being so vague. I'm trying to be detailed without giving away too much information for security purposes. I'm testing the API calls in a local server on my computer using XAMPP. The documentation for the API and the endpoints can be found at https://api.rmaster.com. I hope this helps. The endpoints I'm using are the /token endpoint to generate the token (which works) and the /catalogattributes endpoint to get product information (what I'm trying to do).

Comment: @rigneyj106  If the above code is what's working, then that's not really the code we need to see.  We need to see the code that you've tried that _isn't_ working.

Comment: @PatrickQ, I've edited the question and it now includes the code that isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so now explain _in what way_ it isn't working.  What _is_ happening?  What _should be_ happening?  How/where are you making a request (which should be a POST request) to this file?

Comment: I'm trying to get the 'catalogattributes' to show up in the browser on my local server using the GET.php file. I need the TOKEN that I got using POST in the auth.php file and I need to include it somehow in the GET request to get it to work. I get this error when I pull the GET.php up in the browser: **Notice: Undefined index: TOKEN in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\GET.php on line 20**. Which tells me that `$_POST['TOKEN']` isn't working and I don't know why.

Comment: How exactly do you expect `$_POST['TOKEN']` to be populated if you're just loading the file in your browser?  The $_POST superglobal is only populated when you do a POST request and send data in the request.  To be honest, I'm not really sure why you have two different files here.  Just put this code after the code where you get the token and call it a day.

Comment: I didn't know that is how it worked, honestly. I'm not well-versed in PHP and it's something I'm trying to get better at. I was following an article on API integration with PHP and it wasn't very detailed at certain points. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: To clarify the end of my last comment, if you're going to put this code after the other code, then you'll obviously need to change the token-related variables to be whatever variable you put the token in.  Don't just copy/paste the above and think it will work.